# How to fix error: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: sql-server, integer, overflow, sqldatatypes, arithmetic-expressions

I just used `count` function in query statement but got an error as shown below:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM [my_table_data]
```

Error messages:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Please help me to find the solution!

Comment: Are you expecting a count exceeding 2 billion? If not, you may have some unconstrained or under-constrained joins in your `[my_table_data]` data source. There might also be a calculation or data conversion completely separate from the `count(*)` in that source that is triggering the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try [BIG_COUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-big-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) instead. I believe it's supported since SQL Server 2012

```
SELECT big_count(*) FROM [my_table_data]
```

Comment: I think it's called COUNT_BIG :)